# How to do I check with ssh that my Windows 10 pc is ready for remote connection?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, sleep, openssh

I wake my Windows 10 PC with `wakeonlan` and connect with a remote desktop service. However if I try to connect too soon after waking the PC the connection fails and I have to try again.

Is there a way to check that the PC is ready for a connection before trying to a launch the client?

My own progress so far

```bsh
if ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 user@machine.com 'tasklist | findstr "Process Name"'; then Do this
else
    echo Not Ready
fi
```

Comment: Perhaps a ping check? A successful pings exit code $? is 0, and a timeout one is 1 for me

Comment: from your comment I saw my question was not asking what I intended. I have tried ping but it did not provide the information I was after.

Comment: Ah, ok, I guess you can still bash-script in a repeated check with `ssh` to see if it connects. Once it works perhaps you can sleep for a certain amount and *then* attempt to connect remotely?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Windows 10 PC responds to pings, you could make a bash script to check and wait until a ping is received successful.
Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash #force interpreter to use bash
wakeonlan <ip> #whatever you use to wake it up

sleep 20 #20 second delay

ping <ip address>
if [ $? == 0 ] #if the ping responded and didn't time out
then
    <send command>
else
    <ping wasnt successfully returned here, so do something else>
fi
```

You might want to adapt this to a While-type loop which waits until the Windows 10 PC responds back, and perhaps add a timeout to the ping command. Though, this is a basic framework that should work, *assuming the Windows PC responds to pings to begin with*.

EDIT:

To respond to OP's update, pings won't work if the Windows PC needs time to initialise after connecting to the network. Instead you can loop trying to connect over SSH (which is what I understand is needed to proceed), and then once successful, start the next command. The exit code for SSH might also help with this.